# Getting an error when concatenating string in python

Tags: python, string

Any idea why Im getting a syntax error on `cGrantCreate`

```
if(Viewdata[4][f] == 'true'):
    # The line below gives me a syntax error, all values Im adding are valid and print separately 
    cGrantCreate = "grant insert on "+data[1][d]+"."+data[2][d]+"."+data[3][d]" to " + data[0][d]
    cur.execute(cGrantCreate)
    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have better luck if you invest more time in making your code easily readable on the page (my advice: spend lines, not width, because it's easier to scan visually and spot errors).

```
cGrantCreate = (
    "grant insert on " + 
    data[1][d] + 
    "." + 
    data[2][d] + 
    "." + 
    data[3][d] +    # This one was missing.
    " to " +
    data[0][d]
)
```

Also, learn about `str.join()`.

Answer (score 2):

Note also that a much more pythonic and understandable notation is to use f-strings, which are both easy to understand (compared to the older .format) and have good performance versus scale. Here is how you would do it for your code.

```
cGrantCreate = f"grant insert on {data[1][d]}.{data[2][d]}.{data[3][d]} to {data[0][d]}"
```

This is much easier to read and it will handle if your data is not a string.

Answer (score 1):

please add a plus sign between `data[3][d]` and  `" to "` to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `+` sign between `data[3][d]` and `"to"`.

Your code should look like this:

```
if(Viewdata[4][f] == 'true'):
    # The line below gives me a syntax error, all values Im adding are valid and print separately 
    cGrantCreate = "grant insert on "+data[1][d]+"."+data[2][d]+"."+data[3][d] + " to " + data[0][d]
    cur.execute(cGrantCreate)
    con.commit()
```